# How to get cyrillic text from jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

i render content from jsp to my Ext.Window:

```
    var x = new Ext.Window({
id: 'myWindow', 
title:'Аттрибуты',
layout: 'fit',
autoScroll:false,
width:600,
autoLoad : {  
    url : url_servlet+'form.jsp',  
    scripts: true  
}
})
x.show();
```

And get this:

[image]

When i set UTF8 in jsp:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I get this:

[image]

When i set `cp1251` i get this:

[image]

How to get text in right encoding?

Comment: Your js file(s) with extjs layout setup is not in utf-8. That is.

Comment: Yeah. Really my jsp was in ANSI) Thank you.